# How to optimize this code for less CPU consumption

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a python code that has a infinite loop that scans the pins of raspberry pi conituously. But it is getting very resource consuming for the pi. Can please someone suggest how i could reduce the CPU usage in the code.

```
from matrixKeypad_RPi_GPIO import keypad
from time import sleep
import urllib2
kp = keypad()
var = 1
s1=True
s2=True
s3=True
s4=True
s5=True
s6=True
s7=True
def digit():
    # Loop while waiting for a keypress
    r = None
    while r == None:
        r = kp.getKey()
    return r
while var == 1:
    d=digit()
    if d==1:
        if s1==True :
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r1=ON')
        else:
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r1=OFF')
        s1^=True
    if d==2:
        if s2==True :
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r2=ON')
        else:
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r2=OFF')
        s2^=True
    if d==3:
        if s3==True :
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r3=ON')
        else:
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r3=OFF')
        s3^=True
    if d==4:
        if s4==True :
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r4=ON')
        else:
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r4=OFF')
        s4^=True
    if d==5:
        if s5==True :
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r5=ON')
        else:
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r5=OFF')
        s5^=True
    if d==6:
        if s6==True :
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r6=ON')
        else:
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r6=OFF')
        s6^=True
    if d==7:
        if s7==True :
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r7=ON')
        else:
            urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.2:8080/classicui/CMD?r7=OFF')
        s7^=True
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Other than moving from polling to interrupt-driven behavior?

Comment: Obviously I agree about using some sort of event/interrupt, but this code is actually not polling.  Look at digit() ... either put the sleep in digit, or have digit return None, and have the loop skip directly to the sleep there if None==d.  Also you can hide most of this code in a handle_digit function.

Comment: From a quick look at the source, it looks like that module only provides high-cpu polling.  You may want to look at https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/ for interrupts, or what they appear to call "edge detection"

Comment: How can i make it interrupt driven. I have to call the digit() everytime to take a input from the keypad